# Angular service not working as expected when calling a function in component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a DialogService set as a provider in my core.module.ts. The CoreModule is imported into my app.module.ts.

When deleteProject is called, the confirm dialog appears, but if the user hits cancel it is as if they click OK and the code unexpectedly goes into the if statement (w/ no errors in console). If I replace the service call in the if statement with window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this tenant?') directly in the component it works as expected.

There must be a lesson I need to learn about using singleton services in Angular.

**dialog.service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class DialogService {
  confirm(message?: string): Observable<boolean> {
    const confirmation = window.confirm(message || 'Is it OK?');

    return of(confirmation);
  }
}
```

**delete function in component:**

```
deleteProject(id: number) {
    if (this.dialogService.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this project?')) {
      this.projectService.deleteProject(id).subscribe(() => {
        this.projects.forEach((cur, index) => {
          if (id === cur.id) {
            this.projects.splice(index, 1);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause result is an Observable you need to `subscribe` to the `dialogService.confirm` instead of using it in the `if` statement. Then you can put `if` statement inside it and compare result returned with `of(confirmation)`

Also you can change the `delete` condition a bit

```
this.dialogService.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this project?').subscribe(isConfirmed => {

   if(isConfirmed) {
      this.projectService.deleteProject(id).subscribe(() => {
        const index = this.projects.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
        index !== -1 && this.projects.splice(index, 1);
      });
   }

})
```

Comment: Should have realized this. Thank you. Downvoter probably just thinks it is an amateur question. I stole the service idea from here: https://stackblitz.com/angular/vqmqnrpgrnk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcrisis-center%2Fcrisis-detail.component.ts and didn't realize it returned an observable.